# Data is showing in console but not in screen - reactjs

Tags: reactjs

why am i not seeing the data in my screen when I map over "this.state.viciados" if i can see the data in the console? I have seen this problem in stack overflow but the only answer in that qustion doesn't work.

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
super(props);
this.state = {
  viciados: []
}

}


componentDidMount() {
this.getViciados();
}

 getViciados = _ => {
fetch("http://localhost:3000/dependentes")
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(response => {
    this.setState({ viciados: response.data })
    //console.log(response.data);
  })
  .catch(err => console.log(err));
}



render() {


 const viciados = this.state.viciados.map(viciado => {
  console.log(viciado['id_viciados'], viciado["nome_viciado"]);
  <div key={viciado['id_viciados']}>{viciado["nome_viciado"]}</div>
});
return (
  <div className="App">
    {viciados}
  </div>
);
}
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to `return` data from `map`:

```
const viciados = this.state.viciados.map(viciado => {
  return <div key={viciado['id_viciados']}>{viciado["nome_viciado"]}</div>
});
```